# Dropzone removing a file after upload

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to allow a user upload a max of 3 images.  All is working fine however I want to remove the image from the server.  This is working fine when the page initially loads.  I check server to see if any of the 3 files exist and load them with their server name in the dropzone area.

```
var fs1 = <?php echo $filesize1; ?>;
if(fs1 != 0)
{
var mockFile1 = { name: "<?php echo $id; ?>-1.<?php echo $ext1; ?>", size: <?php echo $filesize1; ?> };
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile1);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile1, "/logos/<?php echo $id; ?>-1.<?php echo $ext1; ?>");
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile1);
file_up_names[0] = "<?php echo $id; ?>-1.<?php echo $ext1; ?>";
}

var fs2 = <?php echo $filesize2; ?>;
if(fs2 != 0)
{
var mockFile2 = { name: "<?php echo $id; ?>-2.<?php echo $ext2; ?>", size: <?php echo $filesize2; ?> };
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile2);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile2, "/logos/<?php echo $id; ?>-2.<?php echo $ext2; ?>");
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile2);
file_up_names[1] = "<?php echo $id; ?>-2.<?php echo $ext1; ?>";
}

var fs3 = <?php echo $filesize3; ?>;
if(fs3 != 0)
{
var mockFile3 = { name: "<?php echo $id; ?>-3.<?php echo $ext3; ?>", size: <?php echo $filesize3; ?> };
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile3);
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile3, "/logos/<?php echo $id; ?>-3.<?php echo $ext3; ?>");
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile3);
file_up_names[2] = "<?php echo $id; ?>-3.<?php echo $ext1; ?>";
}

myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - <?php echo $num_images; ?>;
```

When I uploaded an image, I check server and using AJAX save it to the server.  JSON returns the file image name and size. I rename the image when it is uploaded to uniqueID-1.jpg or uniqueID-2.jpg or uniqueID-3.jpg depending on the what images have been uploaded previously.  So if only one image has been uploaded, the next one gets renamed uniqueID-2.jpg and so on.

Note: fs1, fs2 and fs3 are js variables that are set to the file size of images already uploaded when the page loads.

Here is my full code so far:

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var file_up_names = new Array;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", { // Make the     #my-awesome-dropzone a dropzone
    url: "new-logo.php",
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png',
    thumbnailWidth: 260,
    thumbnailHeight: 120,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove Logo',
    accept: function(file, done) {
        console.log("Uploaded");
        done();
    },
    success: function( file, response ){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(obj.filename + " " + obj.filesize);
        var fn = obj.filename;
        var fnsize = obj.filesize;
        file_up_names.push(obj.filename);

        $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').html(fn);
        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "logos/" + fn);  
    },
    removedfile: function(file) {   
        x = confirm('Do you want to delete this logo?');
        if(!x)  return false;
        for(var i = 0; i < file_up_names.length; ++i) 
        {       
          alert(file_up_names[i] + " " + file.name);
          if(file_up_names[i] == file.name) 
          {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete-logo.php',
                data: "file_name="+file_up_names[i],
                dataType: 'html'
            });
            myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles + 1;
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
          }
        }
    }
```

});

So here is the issue that I cannot seem to sort.

Lets say I upload an image called test.jpg and this get renamed to 15-2.jpg.  This name gets stored in the array of file names no problem.  But when I click the Remove Logo link I alert out the file name from the array file_up_names and the file.name property value for testing.

The file.name is showing still as test.jpg so it never will match the 15-2.jpg in the file_up_names array.

The success is changing the file name but this is not globally set so the removedfile cannot see the updated file name from server.

How can I set the file.name to be 15-2.jpg (i.e. the served file name returned by JSON in success) rather than test.jpg?